# How can I disconnect telethon client, when an event handler does not received any new message event, even after waiting for specific time?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I wanna disconnect client if I didn't received any message even after waiting for 2 minutes.

But it keeps on waiting for ever.

I feel await_for is an alternative but I looking for solution right here itself anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.!!

```
client.connect()
#send message in chat

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
# wait for some reply message
    if received message:
        # do some thing
    else no message:
        client.disconnect()

client.run_until_diconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

- Dissconnect is an asynchronous function i.e coroutine.
- Use `await client.disconnect()` instead.

Comment: Please avoid providing code-only answers without an explanation on why your code resolves the question. While the code may solve the problem, the answer is not useful in understanding why it solves it.